# Is "good job" a suitable phrase for communicating with your boss？

Tags: phrase-usage, email

I just finished a task with my boss‘s support. And in the summary email, I said "I believe we've done a good job already.", with the final file. I also said "Please let me know if you have more suggestions" but I am now a bit worried it might offend him.

Could anyone let me know how should I deal with this?

Thank you for your answer in advance.

Comment: Sounds OK to me. Why do you think it sounds 'offended'? What job does 'already' do in that sentence? Is that what is worrying you?

Comment: Cause somehow seems I am evaluating his work so :(, BUT so glad to here you think it's ok. I use already as this stage is close to the end and I am looking for the next step

Comment: *I am now a bit worried it might sound **offensive***, not ***offended***. The adjective "offensive" describes what you think using "Good job" might sound like. You'd use the Past Participle "offended" to describe your boss's possible reaction: *I am now a bit worried **he** might be **offended.***

Comment: It seems to me you are expressing satisfaction at the good results from working together, and thanking your boss for his help. You may wish to make this last point explicit. In general, we will only offend if we evaluate someone's work negatively (praise is always welcomed), unless in a very deferential and hierarchical society maybe?

Comment: 'Sound offended' would mean that it sounds as though _you_ are offended. I think you mean 'it might offend my boss' or 'might sound offensive'.

Comment: Thank you, yes I do mean it might sound offensive. And hopefully, it's not a big deal as I just want to express my appreciation and submit my work. :D I am slightly worried because I don't want to sound bossy myself. And thank you again for the clarification.

Comment: I think to say * **We've** done a good job.* shouldn't be offensive, but just *Good job!* or *You've done a good job.* might very well be offensive to a boss. Usually it's the job of a boss to judge a subordinate's work, not the other way around.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I suppose the OP is concerned as to whether complementing their boss on a good piece of work could be seen as patronising, or worse still sarcastic. And that can be a very fine line dependent on many factors including age, the type of person the boss is, the manner in which it is said etc. It is really only something that a person can judge for themselves. And the question is, in any case, more about relationships, than it is the English language.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing 'offensive' about the expression "good job". It isn't particularly informal but it isn't overly formal either. Opinions may vary, but we don't give opinion-based answers on this site.

Some people are what you might call 'hypercritical' - constantly looking for fault, quick to assume the worst about others. If you have a boss like that then I suppose it is possible he might find the language a little formal. Some people in business expect 'corporate speak' (an excessively formal, cliche-ridden, responsibility-avoiding form of language that sadly has become the norm in some businesses). In such an environment, you might have instead written "*I trust that we have now satisfactorily completed the task to specification, but please advise me if there is anything further I can do*"... but really, I wouldn't worry, you won't have 'offended' anyone.

Comment: What could be a bit rude is telling your boss "Good job" in response to something they did, as it makes it seem like you're evaluating their performance, and that might be where the OP got the idea that "Good job" is offensive - but in OP's context, I don't see a problem either.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski Perhaps, although that would be opinion-based. My current line manager would not be offended at all if I said that, we both have different skill sets and there is a mutual respect. In my answer, I tried to describe the kind of boss that might not like it - someone who constantly tries to reinforce the heirarchy.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski but OP *didn't* tell his boss "good job".  The phrase was "I believe we've done a good job", which has a totally different connotation.